# CFSET Invoking Function without variable

Tags: coldfusion, return-value, coldfusion-11

New pretty new with this language, started code with it this week.

So my problem is the new company that I started with uses CF11 and they mainly only code with tags. I want to know if is possible to call `cfset` without a variable declaration.

If not what is the better way to call functions (that don't have return) with tags?

```
<cfset myFunction()>
```

I usually call my initiate functions at cfset, but they all have returning.

```
<cfset something = #initSomething()#>
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but it's good to get in the habit of knowing when to use or not use pound signs `#` :) In most all cases, pound signs are only needed if A) the variable is within `<cfoutput>` tags OR B) the variable is enclosed in quotes. So you don't need them for that last example:  `<cfset something = initSomething()>`

Comment: "they mainly only code with tags"  If you prefer script style syntax, take a look at [cfscript](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfscript.html). As of CF11, most everything you can do in CFML is supported in cfscript.  See also cfscript cheat sheet https://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/coldfusion/cfscript/

Comment: I came from python, node... im kinda struggling with coldfusion, to many # and tags to use haha, im getting still getting used to it, but thanks for all the info

Comment: @DiegoVinícius If you use Node, definitely look into cfscript. You'll probably find it much easier to get your head around.

Comment: @DiegoVinícius Is this function coming from a CFC or one you created in-line in code? I ask because you mention `initSomething()`. When you instantiate the CFC, you may or may not need to actually call an `init` function.

Comment: On my constructor (init) im calling private inside functions to setup the environment and load all variables, since that variables is globaly scoped i dont return in function i make the bind

Comment: You may just be able to set these up within the `Application.cfc` and not have to worry with an `init()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, invoking a function without capturing the result is perfectly fine. Sadly, there used to be a lot of that syntax in older CF documentation. It gave the erroneous impression you MUST capture the result of a function (and use extra pound signs everywhere). Neither is true.  Even if a function *does* return something, you're not required to capture the result. Only if you wish to use it for something later. You're always free to invoke a function and completely ignore the result.  So both of these are valid:

```
<!--- 1. capture result ---> 
<cfset result = getTimeNow()>
<!--- 2. ignore result ---> 
<cfset getTimeNow()>

<!--- sample function --->
<cffunction name="getTimeNow" return="date">
    <cfreturn now()>
</cffunction>
```

Technically, there's nothing stopping you from capturing the result of a function that doesn't return anything. However, the "result" variable will be undefined, so it really serves no purpose.

```
 <cfset result = doNothing()>
 <!--- this will error --->
 <cfoutput>#result#</cfoutput>

 <!--- sample function --->
 <cffunction name="doNothing" return="void">
    <!--- function that returns nothing --->
 </cffunction>
```

Comment: @Diego Vinícius - Good spot. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Nope, tks for the help